# How to contribute to 'TurtleBot' Project in Outreachy Round 13?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to start contributing to the TurtlBot project in Outreachy Round 13 .

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/245331/how-to-contribute-to-%27turtlebot%27-project-in-outreachy-round-13?/) by [Aditi](https://answers.ros.org/users/28193/aditi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-10-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't know much about Outreachy, but it looks like OSRF is already part of Outreachy and has a proposed Turtlebot project open: https://github.com/osrf/osrf_wiki/wiki/Outreachy .

According to their [Application Instructions](https://github.com/osrf/osrf_wiki/wiki/Outreachy#application-template-for-participants) it looks like you need to apply for Outreachy and email OSRF directly, asking to work on the Turtlebot project.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-10-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1